# Block hover higher another block

Tags: css, hover

In yellow square I have a hover effect, but when hover display the higher the green block. I need what would be the hover effect of only at yellow square.

I tried to use `z-index` - did not help.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
}
.wrapper {
  border:2px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.block__one {
  background-color:green;
  z-index:5;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align:center;
}
.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color:yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index:10;
}

.list:hover .list__hover {
  opacity:1;
  bottom:0;
}

.list__hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-50px;
  transition: bottom 0.5s;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:4;
}

.block__two {
  background-color:red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
   z-index:5;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block__one">
    <ul class="item">
      <li class="list">
        <div class="list__hover"></div>
      </li>
            <li class="list">
        <div class="list__hover"></div>
     
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block__two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain I've 100% understood your post, but I believe that all you need is to add

```
overflow:hidden
```

to the .list class

Check if the snippet is doing what you want:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
}
.wrapper {
  border:2px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.block__one {
  background-color:green;
  z-index:5;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align:center;
}
.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color:yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index:10;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.list:hover .list__hover {
  opacity:1;
  bottom:0;
}

.list__hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-50px;
  transition: bottom 0.5s;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:4;
}

.block__two {
  background-color:red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
   z-index:5;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block__one">
    <ul class="item">
      <li class="list">
        <div class="list__hover"></div>
      </li>
            <li class="list">
        <div class="list__hover"></div>
     
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block__two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Incredible. Its so easy. ty very match )

Comment: Can you even use transition without pseudo-classes like `:hover`? I think @Григорий code is full of mistakes. For example, there's missing ending `</li>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using first `height` of `0%` and then transitioning it to `50%`. Also check your code, there's a few mistakes in it. You could, for example, use W3 validator.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.block__one {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.list:hover .list__hover {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 50%;
  transition: linear .5s;
}

.list__hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

.block__two {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block__one">
    <ul class="item">
      <li class="list">
        <div class="list__hover"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <div class="list__hover"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block__two"></div>
</div>
```